# Using "Thank you" and "Cheers"

Tags: salutations

Is it sensible to use both "Thank you" and "Cheers" in ending an email?
For example if I sign off.

> Thank you, I am looking forward to receiving your response.
>
> Cheers,
> (insert name here)

would it's **simultaneous** use be **obvious** to most people as being redundant?

(I can get rid of the "thank you" all together and leave the "cheers" to serve the purpose of a thanks and goodbye, but lets say I want to keep both - like "**over yonder**")

Comment: there is an important and subtle distinction between the two questions. I'm not asking for a definition of "cheers" or whether you should use it on an american, but instead its simultaneous use relative to "thank you".

Comment: Just wanted to point out that 'cheers' is not something a lot of American English speakers use and some may not necessarily know what it means (although the context usually makes it pretty obvious)

Comment: @ user1297102: But you're asking about *the fact of [possible] redundancy being noticed and/or judged*. If the two words are considered sufficiently "different", there's no redundancy anyway. Whatever - the weirdest thing for me would be that you *look forward to **hearing** the response to an email*. I'd normally just *look forward to it* - but if I needed to say how I expected to actually perceive the response, I'd *look forward to **reading** it*.

Comment: I frequently use *I look forward to hearing from you* or similar as an idiom for *I look forward to (receiving) your response*. And I used it in letters before e-mail existed. See *Chambers* [http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/] meaning 4 under *hear* "*intrans* (*usually* **hear from someone**) to be contacted by them, especially by letter or telephone."

Comment: thanks for all the responses, I'll keep the rest in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's *possible* - you just type the words!

Is it sensible or appropriate? That really depends on who you're writing to and your familiarity with them. Personally, I would use *Cheers* only to a friend or close colleague, as it quite informal.  Why not:

> I look forward to hearing from you.
>   Thank you,

or

> Thank you.
>   Looking forward to hearing from you,

But don't be too familiar with people you don't know well.

Comment: Maybe it's me but I have a little problem with your 2nd example.  The "Looking forward to hearing from you," seems too long for a closing and is not a complete sentence if it's intended to be the last line before the closing.  I think your 1st example is very good and adequately formal. :-)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm not asking whether its appropriate in a formal/informal sense or whether its "possible" to physically type it (haha i changed my original question) but whether most people would see it as being sort of redundant?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I don't know that I would actually use it that way round - I was copying the OP's example. "It's not a complete sentence" - No, but nor are most sign-off phrases (e.g. *With best wishes*, *Yours faithfully*, *Looking forward to seeing you soon*, etc.).  Personally, I don't see length as an issue here, although if it were more than half-a-line (or, say, 6-8 words) long, then I might think it too long. Also, I would use *Looking forward to hearing from you* only if the letter / message / e-mail specifically required a reply - it's a kind of a hint that I want a reply soon!

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, basically.  :-)